# 403 Forbidden when calling api behind an api gateway custom domain name

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, tls1.2, amazon-route53

I have a setup where an API which is in AWS lambda is exposed via an API gateway. The API gateway has a custom domain name(TLS) and Route 53 has an Alias record that allows me to call the API through my url eg. https://myapi.example.com. API is accessible through this URL.

I also have an alternate service exposed via an ALB hosted in AWS ECS.
The idea is to route 50% of the traffic using Route 53 weighted rule to ECS and the rest to lambda.

If I make a call to the weighted record, the API gateway throws a 403. I am wondering if this is even achievable or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The client https request is terminated on the ali gateway.  The gateway will need to be configured for each domain you want to add.

Each domain will also need a certificate created and configured in the api gateway.  Using a wildcard cert can make that part easier.

To use a custom domain:

1. Add custom domain to api gateway
2. Generate and Associate a key for the domain on the gateway
3. Add a dns record using the new domain

Check the amazon api documentation for [custom domains](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html) and [api domain mapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/rest-api-mappings.html).  You can repeat the "add custom domain" step multiple times.

Comment: Thanks @spazm. What I want to achieve is use the route 53 weighted rules to send traffic to the api in lambda or to the ecs server behind an ALB. I will update the question but this solution of adding custom domains for all the domains will not work in my use-case.

Comment: That's a bit beyond my experience.  What is the name of the weighted domain? If it is different than myapi, you'll need to have it added in the gateway.  Fascinating question!

Comment: You might want or need a load balancer, which will also help if you need any per-user stickiness for subsequent requests for a user to go to the same service.   (But an alb sure isn't free)

Comment: It was different. I ended up setting up the ALB and now the setup works. Thanks for the explanation on why it didn't :)